# I can't boot after deleting the first ubuntu?

Tags: boot

I installed ubuntu 11.10 and after a while it get damaged and I install another one in another partition . After I boot to the new one I delete the old one ( I format its partition ) . When I restart I couldn't boot .
What is the solution ?

Comment: You installed boot loader from deleted ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled ubuntu and it solved .

Answer (score 1):

Without error messages or more detailed explanations of what happens, it is really hard to tell what the computer is doing. However, a possible cause of errors is that your boot loader (GRUB) cannot find the old version of Ubuntu and fails while it is trying to create the boot-up menu.

You can try to recover the system using various commands from a LiveCD, but if you don't want to deal with all that, a simpler solution is to just install the new one again. It gets you up and running with the least amount of fuss.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I think the problem is GRUB too . I do the same as you said before . I mean I reinstall ubuntu and delete the old one and I got this problem . I have many files on it and it is really hard to copy it and delete all ubuntus and install a new one . Is there any way to repair this one ?

Comment: You could try Super Grub Disk that is very useful in solving boot related issues.

Comment: @mahdiar, apart from @devius' suggesting about Super Grub Disk which is the best in your current situation, I would suggest that if you ever do reinstall everything, put `/home` on its own partition -- that way, if you want to reinstall the whole system or even share the same home folder between two different Linux installations, it is much simpler. This doesn't help your current situation, of course, but may be something to consider for the future (next computer, for instance).

Comment: @ devius , Thanks . Could you please tell me more about it ? How can I do that ? @ Lakritsbollar, Thanks for your response .